# yii2 sqlite fails to resolve table names

Tags: php, sqlite, yii2, generator, gii

I found some bug in sqlite-conf, I don't know, but it doesnt seems to work as it intended.
The thing I have the following `db.php` file

```
return [
'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
'dsn' => 'sqlite:somedb',
'charset' => 'utf8',
```

];

I can create and run migrations

```
    use yii\db\Migration;
    use yii\db\sqlite\Schema;

class m160222_083002_create_some_table extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $this->createTable('some_table', [
            'id' => Schema::TYPE_PK,
            'name' => Schema::TYPE_STRING
        ]);
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->dropTable('some_table');
    }
}
```

these are works fine, creates table etc.

```
    $ ./yii migrate
Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.7)

Total 1 new migration to be applied:
        m160222_083002_create_some_table

Apply the above migration? (yes|no) [no]:y
*** applying m160222_083002_create_some_table
    > create table some_table ... done (time: 0.109s)
*** applied m160222_083002_create_some_table (time: 0.170s)


1 migration was applied.

Migrated up successfully.
```

But then comes some magic.
I **can't** use gii generators from my local server, e.g.

```
somelocal.loc/gii/model
```

when I enter table name like

> some_table

Answer is

> Table 'some_table' does not exist.

However running gii model generator from CLI runs perfect

```
    $ ./yii gii/model --tableName=some_table --modelClass=someTable
Running 'Model Generator'...

The following files will be generated:
        [new] models/someTable.php

Ready to generate the selected files? (yes|no) [yes]:y

Files were generated successfully!
Generating code using template "/var/www/sweethouse.loc/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-gii/generators/model/default"...
 generated models/someTable.php
done!
```

it generates the following code

```
    namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "some_table".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $name
 */
class someTable extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'some_table';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 255]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
        ];
    }
}
```

But if only

```
somelocal.loc/gii/model
```

didn't work, that wouldn't be pity, CLI generator is more friendly.

But the most important problem for me that mysite cant resolve tablenames,
ActiveRecord doesn't see it, and crashes site with following error

```
    Database Exception – yii\db\Exception

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: some_table
Failed to prepare SQL: SELECT * FROM `some_table`
Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => HY000
    [1] => 1
    [2] => no such table: some_table
)
↵
Caused by: PDOException

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: some_table

in /var/www/mysite/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php at line 225
```

And controller action, where I want to access my table values

```
public function actionSome()
{
    $some = someTable::find()->all();

    return $this->render('some',[
        'some' => $some
    ]);
}
```

The following error comes only with sqlite3 database

Comment: should I send it to yii2 repo as issue?
It seems a little strange for everyone

Answer (score 1):

Set the dsn value with the system path to the database.

To make it portable, use the path alias provided by yii:

```
'dsn' => 'sqlite:@app/db/database.db',
```

Comment: Are you starting with one of the apps? The alias is defined in the basic and advanced template but I'm not sure if it is defined by just installing yii http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/667/yii-2-list-of-path-aliases-available-with-default-basic-and-advanced-app/